# Docker running on a amazonlinux:2 with an apache webserver returns 503 service unavailable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-linux

Setting up a docker container containing a apache webserver running on a linux OS.

I am trying to setup a docker environment where i run an apache webserver at a amazonlinux:2 OS through docker. I am able to set up everything but when i load the url on localhost it returns a "503 service unavailable". I have tried to switch ports etc. Nothing works even though this is the modules etc. used for deploying my servers non-docker. I know stackoverflow isn't meant for very code specific issues i just can't seem to solve this one on my own. Thanks in advance.

The following that might be relevant: Docker inspect

```
[
{
    "Id": "8f9997578a8f16655e7e1c2c32b4be5ec06b79a886c73dd8151c6b36993c99de",
    "Created": "2020-04-30T11:25:00.7273382Z",
    "Path": "/usr/sbin/init",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 33131,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2020-04-30T11:25:02.2676346Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:ba3c5108c23dcee592b14fe824776b562fe64b9685e8930e0ba365230488c558",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f9997578a8f16655e7e1c2c32b4be5ec06b79a886c73dd8151c6b36993c99de/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f9997578a8f16655e7e1c2c32b4be5ec06b79a886c73dd8151c6b36993c99de/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f9997578a8f16655e7e1c2c32b4be5ec06b79a886c73dd8151c6b36993c99de/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8f9997578a8f16655e7e1c2c32b4be5ec06b79a886c73dd8151c6b36993c99de/8f9997578a8f16655e7e1c2c32b4be5ec06b79a886c73dd8151c6b36993c99de-json.log",
    "Name": "/webserver",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "test_default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": [],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Capabilities": null,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "shareable",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": true,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": [
            "label=disable"
        ],
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": null,
        "ReadonlyPaths": null
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/632952313b6924721dbb70ce572bddc5960412d27c7c97e55a5e988fda2e4340-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7928f2a813c8abbff2c73e9dfcf0f6608e6da85cd775600d683025c83d3ad57c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/81ad8aaf872ad9aebfc09ed470c0f1b7d2be073c7b54acffb46262e08c4da626/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/175c01b27dbb0c18765431cfe8217c49ce2dc5ddc2c690fac98a7c06f7954a86/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/db4dbbd7229b9024e9e8d6a4a04cb06e7cb11e106b266831237da74f64e908a9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/43434aaa5b69556dfa16e8bf5eed24be80453ba2b9b9aa46293c92676ca895fd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4abf428a00de2f5b3d69fe5ad95840eb23bafab9f3ce1dbe338816a64afb8b45/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f29b5cfeaa8f70f63cb823574f3c12ae7225171d880f52f9152d829510785c37/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/009e8af3a21902fb29a7dd34bf70bf2e9a18e92d4a19d61af4efedc3a418f47d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5f253c50fd411d5b6feb6b7530c4063074f825bd7d5638d9d3fe24f48d9fc15d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c09ac469770ad1a64ad6d2cf8e329758dc9c396a10284f533fd4e88abb8b7504/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f23f1a035669c8d634ec2e6d6526314194d102c3e923b7c192ce3275e3a79b6e/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/214a494e5be1bca7b560ea3c2767fc26af350cdce8a717c2c325bc124e8e2010/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/43b742e71bf54d2f9beb64ad80b5737f4892d0078213d5fb455e77da0816f0fd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/31310c16a674414fdb27f9792eeae7301618d960a322d899baa77b7fa89db239/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6fec2d57bdf41b2bac187ae31518c9a3dda15af2ba2397e1524a96fb6b6df036/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eb1092c999afd90a70bc365518a95bbaf198f8462db80e5fa959cf2f1f60ec23/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cf7cf93961372b8bbf2fe3a1b3ad849ffce0cae129b7c89b5d5a182ce397da12/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/330df7c9d56f024ab1c9d4157c128d709b37272001d4abbf8b6871c6b9089f15/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/632952313b6924721dbb70ce572bddc5960412d27c7c97e55a5e988fda2e4340/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/632952313b6924721dbb70ce572bddc5960412d27c7c97e55a5e988fda2e4340/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/632952313b6924721dbb70ce572bddc5960412d27c7c97e55a5e988fda2e4340/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "8f9997578a8f",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "3306/tcp": {},
            "443/tcp": {},
            "8080/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": true,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
        ],
        "Cmd": null,
        "Image": "test_webserver_setup",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/usr/sbin/init"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "f8dfaed17cde38b55e050b86a43bb0dd5429ad6c21baad83b389a19df88869b9",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "test",
            "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yaml",
            "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/private/docker/test",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "webserver_setup",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.4"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "46e724f336d8d865616f32abcc74d1ddc7dd7bd8cb15afa84992c68f38e65c8c",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "3306/tcp": null,
            "443/tcp": null,
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/46e724f336d8",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "test_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "webserver_setup",
                    "8f9997578a8f"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "d7c1b2428c7c8ffa4d64079053a90edbbeead91d334edee406fd848a653d0304",
                "EndpointID": "1721124b84f8dd31868ebacf4ea0e86c3fc627d769d157003792744e7e1e3394",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }


     }
    }
]
```

Here is my docker-compose file which i run with the "docker-compose up" command:

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  webserver_setup:
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    privileged: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: webserver_dockerfile
    container_name: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

And the webserver_dockerfile

    FROM amazonlinux:2

COPY ./source/ /var/www/html

#ENTRYPOINT ["/"]
RUN yum install sudo -y
RUN sudo  yum update -y
RUN sudo amazon-linux-extras install -y lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 php7.2
RUN sudo yum install -y httpd mariadb-server

#install dependencies
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y \
initscripts \
mod_ssl \
gcc \
memcached \
openssl-devel \
php72-bcmath \
php72-cli \
php72-common \
php72-dba \
php72-dbg \
php72-devel \
php72-enchant \
php72-fpm \
php72-gd \
php72-gmp \
php72-imap \
php72-intl \
php72-json \
php72-ldap \
php72-mbstring \
php72-mcrypt \
php72-mysqlnd \
php72-odbc \
php72-opcache \
php72-pdo \
php72-pdo-dblib \
php72-pecl-igbinary \
php72-pecl-imagick \
php72-pecl-memcached \
php72-pecl-oauth \
php72-pecl-ssh2 \
php72-pecl-uuid \
php72-pecl-yaml \
php72-pgsql \
php72-process \
php72-pspell \
php72-recode \
php72-snmp \
php72-soap \
php72-tidy \
php72-xml \
php72-xmlrpc \
php72-zip \
php7-pear \
mysql57-server \
mongodb-org \
nano \
man \
&& yum clean all

#setup webserver and access to document directory
RUN sudo systemctl enable httpd
RUN sudo usermod -a -G apache root
RUN sudo chown -R root:apache /var/www
RUN sudo chmod 2775 /var/www && find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;
RUN find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;


#remove default config and prepare server with custom config
#RUN echo "ServerName gamingbuddy.local" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN sed -i 's/Listen 80/Listen 0.0.0.0:8080/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN sed -i '/<Directory \"\/var\/www\">/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN sed -i '/<Directory \"\/var\/www\/html\">/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN touch /etc/httpd/conf/vhost.conf
RUN printf "<VirtualHost *:8080> \
            ServerName localhost \
            <Proxy *> \
                #Allow from localhost \
                Order deny,allow \
                Allow from all \
            </Proxy> \
            ProxyPass / http://172.19.0.1:8080/ retry=0 \
        </VirtualHost>"

RUN rm /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf

RUN echo "Include '/etc/httpd/conf/vhost.conf'" >> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf


EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 3306

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/init"]
#servers are started during build file setup
```

I get an error regarding fastGCI process manager that fails to start and a remount of root and kernel file system. These are the errors and error codes i get:

```
    bash-4.2# systemctl status systemd-remount-fs.service
● systemd-remount-fs.service - Remount Root and Kernel File Systems
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-remount-fs.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-01 12:10:27 UTC; 2min 36s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-remount-fs.service(8)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
  Process: 23 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-remount-fs (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 23 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 01 12:10:27 0ce19e8b1c10 systemd-remount-fs[23]: mount: /: can't find LABEL=/.
May 01 12:10:27 0ce19e8b1c10 systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 01 12:10:27 0ce19e8b1c10 systemd[1]: Failed to start Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
May 01 12:10:27 0ce19e8b1c10 systemd[1]: Unit systemd-remount-fs.service entered failed state.
May 01 12:10:27 0ce19e8b1c10 systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service failed.
```

Error 2:

```
    ● php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-01 12:10:33 UTC; 13min ago
  Process: 253 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize (code=exited, status=78)
 Main PID: 253 (code=exited, status=78)

May 01 12:10:32 0ce19e8b1c10 systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
May 01 12:10:33 0ce19e8b1c10 php-fpm[253]: [01-May-2020 12:10:33] ERROR: [pool www] failed to read the ACL of the socket '/run/php-fpm/www.sock': Operation not supported (95)
May 01 12:10:33 0ce19e8b1c10 php-fpm[253]: [01-May-2020 12:10:33] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
May 01 12:10:33 0ce19e8b1c10 systemd[1]: php-fpm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
May 01 12:10:33 0ce19e8b1c10 systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
May 01 12:10:33 0ce19e8b1c10 systemd[1]: Unit php-fpm.service entered failed state.
May 01 12:10:33 0ce19e8b1c10 systemd[1]: php-fpm.service failed.
```

Comment: *"I know stackoverflow isn't meant for very code specific issues"* - you probably meant the opposite here. This question seems to be better suited for ServerFault, SuperUser or Unix&Linux SE.

Comment: so usually this happens when you deploy and don't have a rolling config in case you've just deployed :)